# Clearing shared preferences in case of oAuth twitter integration in android (eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, twitter, oauth

I tried creating an oAuth based app in android using twitter. But I am facing problems while signing out from the same as the app does not asks the user to re authorize it by asking the credentials to login and directly passes to another layout by clicking on sign in. I cleared all the shared preferences details for logout but not working still.
These are my classes:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "key";
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "sec";

    // Preference Constants
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLoggedIn";
    private static final String PREF_USER_NAME = "twitter_user_name";
    private static final String PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE = "twitter_profile_url";

    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

    // Twitter oauth urls
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";

    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Twitter
    private static Twitter mTwitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;

    /* Any number for uniquely distinguish your request */
    public static final int WEBVIEW_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    // Shared Preferences
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    private RelativeLayout profileLayout, loginLayout;
    private TextView mProfileName;
    private ImageView mProfileImage;
    private EditText mTweetText;

    private Bitmap mProfileBitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Shared Preferences
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "PREFERENCE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);

        loginLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_layout);
        profileLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.profile_layout);
        mProfileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        mProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_profilePicture);
        mTweetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tweet_text);

        updateUI();
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if user currently logged in or not and updates the UI
     */
    private void updateUI() {
        if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
            loginLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            profileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            String username = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "");
            String profilePictureURL = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE, "");
            new LoadProfilePicture().execute(profilePictureURL);
            // Displaying in xml ui
            mProfileName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
        } else {
            loginLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calls when user click tweet button
     * @param view
     */
    public void postTweet(View view) {
        // Call update status function
        // Get the status from EditText
        String status = mTweetText.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(status)) {
            // EditText is empty
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return;
        }

        // update status
        new PostTweetOnTwitter().execute(status);
        mTweetText.setText("");

    }

    /**
     * Calls when user click login button
     * @param view
     */
    public void loginUser(View view) {
        new LoginUserOnTwitter().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Calls when user click logout button
     * @param view
     */
    public void logoutUser(View view) {
        // Clear the shared preferences
         getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN).clear().commit();
        editor.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET).clear().commit();
        editor.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN).clear().commit();
      editor.remove(PREF_USER_NAME).clear().commit();
       editor.remove(PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE).clear().commit();
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();

        updateUI();


    }

    /**
     * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
     * fetched from Shared Preferences
     */
    private boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
        // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }

    /**
     * Function to login user
     */
    class LoginUserOnTwitter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
            mTwitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();
            try {
                requestToken = mTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);

                /**
                 *  Loading twitter login page on webview for authorization
                 *  Once authorized, results are received at onActivityResult
                 *  */
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(WebViewActivity.EXTRA_URL, requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
                startActivityForResult(intent, WEBVIEW_REQUEST_CODE);

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


    }

    /**
     * Saving user information, after user is authenticated for the first time.
     * You don't need to show user to login, until user has a valid access token
     */
    private void saveTwitterInfo(AccessToken accessToken) {

        long userID = accessToken.getUserId();

        User user;
        try {
            user = mTwitter.showUser(userID);

            String username = user.getName();
            String profilePicture = user.getOriginalProfileImageURL();
            /* Storing oAuth tokens to shared preferences */
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
            editor.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
            editor.putString(PREF_USER_NAME, username);
            editor.putString(PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE, profilePicture);
            editor.apply();

        } catch (TwitterException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == WEBVIEW_REQUEST_CODE && data != null) {
                final Uri uri = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("KEY_URI"));
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(MainActivity.URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                        try {
                            AccessToken accessToken = mTwitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                            saveTwitterInfo(accessToken);
                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    updateUI();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            if (e.getMessage() != null) {
                                Log.e("Twitter-->", e.getMessage());

                            } else {
                                Log.e("Twitter-->", "ERROR: Twitter callback failed");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to update status
     */
    class PostTweetOnTwitter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Places JSON
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
            String status = args[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                // Access Token
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

                // Update status
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to load profile picture
     */
    private class LoadProfilePicture extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading profile ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        /**
         * Download image from the url
         **/
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                mProfileBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(args[0]).getContent());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mProfileBitmap;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and set bitmap to imageview
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
            Bitmap image_circle = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(image, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setShader(shader);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(image_circle);
            c.drawCircle(image.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2, image.getWidth() / 2, paint);
            mProfileImage.setImageBitmap(image_circle);

            pDialog.hide();

        }
    }

}
```

I am using web view for calling twitter oAuth.

WebViewActivity.java

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity{

 WebView webView;

    public static String EXTRA_URL = "extra_url";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.auth_dialog);
        setTitle("Login");

        final String url = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
        if (null == url) {
            Log.e("Twitter", "URL cannot be null");
            finish();
        }

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){

                if( url.contains(MainActivity.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)){
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                    resultIntent.putExtra("KEY_URI", uri.toString());
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

                /* closing webview */
                    finish();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);

    }
}
```

I am attaching the screenshots of my app and would like to show how it should work:

[image: screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

[image: screen 3]

The thing what I need is when i tweet something and click on logout and get redirected to sign in screen, I want the app to ask me again for the authorization details. Currently my app switches directly without asking me for any details to tweet screen when used second time after login.

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing this on your `logout button`

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeSessionCookie();
```

Comment: After adding the code snippet, I am getting an error like this:  twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, Config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET); /*TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY cannot be resolved or is not a field*/ There is some issue in the Config part of the code while importing it I guess.

Comment: wait edited code pls check again.. I have removed Config class Filed where I have defined keys and secret key as constant..

Comment: did it help you now? @YogeshPatel

Comment: Welcome, Happy coding!!@YogeshPatel